# Database migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migrate

I just cloned one of my repos to a new Mac, everything was fine but then when I try to rake db:create:all or rake db:migrate, I got this error: (I read something about database.yml file but I don't have it in my project and it all worked on another Mac):

```
rake aborted!
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/fabrizio/Desktop/SkyWalker/imnotatester/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:293:in `setup'
/Users/fabrizio/Desktop/SkyWalker/imnotatester/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/Users/fabrizio/Desktop/SkyWalker/imnotatester/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Is there a config/database.yml file?

Comment: No, there isn't. I read something about it but I never had it in my project...

Comment: Should I add it to /config?

Comment: ... How would a migration work if there's no DB information? How would it know any DB connection or schema information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `database.yml` in `config` directory (near application.rb, boot.rb, routes.rb).

```
# database.yml
development:

  encoding: utf8
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Then call `bundle exec rake db:create && bundler exec rake db:migrate,`. Hope you have `bundler` and `sqlite3` in the `Gemfile`.